# transforming the text data in unix or Linux with text editor like sed or awk or tr

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I have file which have thousand os data, for example IP address enclosed within Parenthesis along with comma and hyphen. Where i would to remove all of them replacing IP address to be appeared into a newline without a blank line or white space..

Below is an example file..

```
$ cat file1
mynetgroup-test (192.19.23.57,-,) (192.19.23.58,-,)
```

My solution as of now as follows but it could be better or streamlined in a better controlled way

```
$ cat file1 | sed -e 's/[(,) ]/\n/g' | tr -d "-" | sed '/^$/d'
mynetgrouptest
192.19.23.57
192.19.23.58
```

Comment: `where should be removing all of them` you mean you need only addresses right? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  `Parenthesis along with comma and hyphen`  this needs `mynetgroup-test` as well

Answer (score 2):

What about just using `grep`?

```
$ egrep -o '[a-z][a-z-]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}' input.txt
mynetgroup-test
192.19.23.57
192.19.23.58
```

Or of course `grep -E` if your OS prefers not to use `egrep`.

This solution merely matches patterns that look like hostnames and IP addresses, and (thanks to grep's `-o` option) prints only the pieces that match, in the order they were seen.

An alternate notation might be to use `grep`'s `-e` option to include multiple regular expressions:

```
egrep -o -e '[a-z][a-z-]+' -e '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}' input.txt
```

Of course, if you *really* want to use other tools, the following might work:

```
$ awk '{print $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$i); print $i } }' input.txt
mynetgroup-test
192.19.23.57
192.19.23.58
```

This prints the first field, then steps through the remaining fields stripping undesirable characters, then printing the fields.

Another awk alternative might be this:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$i) } } 1' OFS="\n" input.txt
```

This does the same stepping-through-fields, then prints the whole record using the `1` shorthand at the end of the script. The OFS variable assignment is slightly different from the `-v` option, but works the same way in this case.

If you don't mind pipes, you can do something like this with sed:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < input.txt | sed -ne '/^[a-z]/{p;b' -e '}' -e 's/[^0-9.]//gp'
```

This separates words onto separate lines for easier processing by sed (as well as mocking up the eventual output format). The sed script then (1) prints any line that starts with a letter, assuming it's a hostname, then `b`ranches which takes us to the next line, and (2) removes any non-IP-address characters from any other lines, and prints them.

The sed notation here was tested with bsd sed, but should work fine with GNU sed as well.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{gsub(/[-,)(]/,"")}1' file
mynetgrouptest
192.19.23.57
192.19.23.58
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need only addresses then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT1:*** In case your Input_file is 100% same as shown samples then following may help you on same too.

```
awk -v RS=" " '{gsub(/\(|,|-|\)/,"");gsub(/$\n$/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** taking a bit regex inspiration from Ghoti sir's solution too.

```
awk -v RS=" " '!/[a-zA-Z]+/{gsub(/[^0-9.]+/,"");gsub(/$\n$/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: @krock1516, please check my EDIT1 too now, it will print all the lines as per your question too, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: @krock1516, cool glad that it helped you, after sometime you could choose any of the answers as correct answer which you think is good, cheers and keep learning and sharing knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the credit. ;) Note that the last (edit 2) solution doesn't handle multiple records well, since the last record on each line is separated by the next field using a newline rather than a space. If you're using gawk or mawk, you might specify `RS='[[:space:]]'` to account for this, but that doesn't work with BSD awk (also used in macOS).

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\((([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+),-,\)/\n\1/g' file

mynetgroup-test 
192.19.23.57 
192.19.23.58
```

you can fine tune the IP address match, but this heuristics should be fine.

Comment: That would be GNU sed because of the `\n`, I guess. This one doesn't look so pretty if you make it portable. :-)

Comment: thx, his script also uses `\n`, so should work for this case.  Perhaps not kosher but I'm not worried about portability on throw away scripts...

Comment: Ah, I try to keep portability in mind with all answers.. You never know what operating system the next visitor who searches for this subject line will be using.